# Slow execution of simple vba macro for excel (mac 2011)

Tags: macos, excel, vba

The following macro runs remarkably slowly in MS Excel for Mac (Office 2011). For 100 data points in the for-next loop, it takes 10 seconds. In a previous version for Office 2004, the line "Application.EnableEvents = False" fixed the problem but not anymore in Office 2011. The code is shown below. Any tips are appreciated.

```
Sub findfirstnonzero3()
    Application.Volatile
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim student, studenter, first, tentor, utdata, yr, startcol, startrow, temp As Integer
    Dim resultatet As Integer
    Dim ignore, resstr As String
    Dim tenta, outp, temprange As Range

    yr = Cells(4, 2).Value
    studenter = Cells(1, 2).Value
    tentor = Cells(2, 2).Value
    utdata = 3
    startrow = 2
    startcol = 5

    Cells(1, utdata).Offset(startrow - 2, 0).Value = "Första tenta"
    For student = 1 To studenter
        temp = 0
        Cells(1, utdata).Offset(startrow + student - 2, 0).Value = 0
        For first = 1 To tentor
            resstr = Cells(startrow + student - 1, startcol).Offset(0, first - 1).Value
            resultatet = Val(resstr)
            temp = first
            If resultatet > 0 Then
                Cells(1, utdata).Offset(startrow + student - 2, 0).Value = temp
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.Volatile` serves no purpose in a subroutine. VBA in 2011 is not particularly fast but it may be useful to switch calculation to manual.

Comment: Thanks. Disabling auto-calculate in the Prefs dramatically speeded up execution (approx 100x). Kind of an inconvenient solution though. I'd like to keep auto-calc.

Comment: @Rory you should post as an answer, it was obviously a good suggestion!
And Dan, you can disable auto-calculate inside the macro, and then reenable it in the end of the macro.

Comment: Thanks for all the good advice. @pgr, could you tell me the command that disables auto-calc locally within the sub? That would make my day.

Comment: That's an easy thing to Google... `Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual` to turn off, `Application.Calculation = xlCalculateAutomatic` to turn on, `Application.Calculate` to calculate now (when it is set to manual).

Comment: @pgr: Thanks... I guess a knowledgeable person like you would have no problem extracting this information from Google - but isn't the whole point with sites like SO that you get good answers collected in one place, under the eyes of wise and experienced people?

Comment: Welcome to SO, I'm glad you like it. Don't forget to upvote answers and comments you find useful.

Comment: Sorry I was too quick... including Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual in the code resulted in an error message "1004 Application-defined or object-defined error". Rest of code same as in original post. What's up?

Comment: However, Application.Calculation =  xlManual or Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual both work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summing up the comments posted here, this is the answer that works for me:

1. Turn off auto-calculation at start of macro using

Application.Calculation = xlManual

or

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

2. At the end of the macro, turn auto-calc back on using

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

or

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Thanks everyone.

D

Answer (score 2):

There is a great way to avoid calculation delays. I had fantastic results with this and now I use it all the time.

Simply put, Excel takes a long time copying data back and forth between the "VBA world" and the "spreadsheet world".

If you do all the "reads" at once, process, and then do all the "writes" at once, you get amazing performance. This is done using **variant arrays** as documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726673.aspx#xlFasterVBA

in the section labeled: **Read and Write Large Blocks of Data in a Single Operation**

I was able to refactor some code I had that took 5 minutes to run and bring it down to 1.5 minutes. The refactoring itself took me only 10 minutes, which is amazing because it was quite complex code.